# using a function in different .c files (c programming 101)

Tags: c, function, declaration, header-files

```
/me/home/file1.c containes function definition:

int mine(int i)
{
    /* some stupidity by me */
}
```

I've declared this function in

```
/me/home/file1.h

int mine(int);
```

if I want to use this function `mine()` in `/me/home/at/file2.c`

To do so, all I need to do is:

```
file2.c

#include "../file1.h"
```

Is that enough? Probably not.

After doing this much, when I compile `file2.c`, I get `undefined reference to 'mine'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will also need to link the object file from file1. Example:

```
gcc -c file2.c
gcc -c ../file1.c
gcc -o program file2.o file1.o
```

Or you can also feed all files simultaneously and let GCC do the work (not suggested beyond a handful of files);

```
gcc -o program file1.c file2.c
```

Comment: Thanks Yann. How can I do this in a Makefile?

Comment: Generally, you can get away with specifying the object files only, and GCC is smart enough to do the rest. I.e.: `program: file1.o file2.o \n\tgcc -o program file1.o file2.o`

Comment: Thanks much for the prompt help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ../ in a header.  Instead, instruct gcc to use the parent directory as include path:

(in the at directory):

```
gcc -I../ -c file2.c
```

Comment: Sometimes there are good reasons for not doing -I../, I wouldn't go so far as to say "don't use ../" is a good general rule.

Answer (score 1):

> After doing this much, when I compile file2.c, I get undefined reference to 'mine'

No, you don't. It's not compiling that causes those errors. It's this other thing, called "linking".

The compiler compiles one "translation unit" - the result of running the preprocessor on one source file, possibly pulling in more stuff via `#include` - at a time, and then the linker sticks these together to make an executable. Typically the same program serves as both the compiler and linker, with different flags, and typically you can tell it to do everything at once (and not save any temporary files for the compiled translation units). But you do need to tell it what to link, and you do need to compile everything that will be linked.